# Time labels hide when I change slotduration to "some values"

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am making a editor, this is def:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    slotDuration: $('input[name="duration"]').val(),
    minTime: $('input[name="start"]').val(),
    maxTime: $('input[name="end"]').val(),
    defaultView: $('#default_view').val(),
    defaultDate: $('input[name="date"]').val(),
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    handleWindowResize: true,
    height: $(window).height() - 200,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: $('#views').val().join(),
        },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    selectable: true
});
```

When I change slotDuration with something like-

00:35:00 or 
00:41:00 or 
00:45:00

This happens:
[image]

But when, slotDuration is 00:15:00, the labels are displayed like:
[image]

When I change duration to 3 mins or 30 mins or 1 hour or 2 or 3 and some more in some fixed pattern... it does display time labels. But for some it doesn't,Why is this happeningg?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/1/ seems to work with those durations. What version of fullCalendar are you using?

Comment: @ADyson fullcalendar 3.0.0

Comment: can you create a working example (e.g. in JSFiddle) which demonstrates the issue? Only because I can't reproduce it. I wonder if the values you're using for minTime and maxTime are playing a part. Are you using the same values each time, and if so, what are you using?